# How to join query select from 2 different database access and sql on VB 2008 express

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How to join query select from 2 different database access 2003 and sql on VB 2008 express?

My query:

```
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Exim_Header.FrgPlus,Exim_Header.FrgMin,Exim_Header.ETD,Exim_Header.ETA,Exim_Header.FrgCury,Exim_Header.FrgNotes, Exim_detail.OCNo from Exim_Header INNER JOIN Exim_detail on Exim_Header.InvNo = Exim_detail.InvNo where Exim_detail.OCNo<>'ORC-L15181'", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds)
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
```

---

```
        Dim Cnn As New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True;" & _
                                      "Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE; Data Source=(LOCAL)")
        Dim sql As String
        Dim strCaseID As String
        strCaseID = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("OCNo").Value

        Cnn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT OEORDH.ORDFISCYR, OEORDH.ORDFISCPER, OEORDH.ORDNUMBER FROM OEORDH WHERE OEORDH.ORDFISCYR like '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and OEORDH.ORDFISCPER >= '" & TextBox2.Text & "' and OEORDH.ORDFISCPER <= '" & TextBox3.Text & "'" 

        Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Cnn)
        Dim das As New DataSet
        dscmd.Fill(das)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = das.Tables(0)
        Cnn.Close()

        End Sub
```

I want to combine 2 query above, where `Exim_detail.OCNo` (access field) = `OEORDH.ORDNUMBER` (SQL field)

Comment: Once filled, the `DataTable`s are independent of the database engines, so you can merge them programatically. You can even use the `DataAdapter.Fill` command on different `DataTables` within the same `DataSet`

Comment: Thanks 'SSS' for your fast response, Can you provide a sample query to combined 2 datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Once filled, the DataTables are independent of the database engines, so you can merge them programatically:

```
'Merge the two datatables'
Dim dtbOleDb As DataTable = tables(0)
Dim dtbSqlServer As DataTable = das.Tables(0)
'1. start with the OleDb table'
Dim dtbMerged As DataTable = dtbOleDb.Copy
'2. Add all the columns from the Sql table'
For Each dcl As DataColumn In dtbSqlServer.Columns
  dtbMerged.Columns.Add(dcl.ColumnName, dcl.DataType)
Next dcl
'3. match the records'
For Each drwMerge As DataRow In dtbMerged.Rows
  For Each drwSqlServer As DataRow In dtbSqlServer.Rows
    If drwSqlServer("ORDNUMBER").ToString = drwMerge("OCNo").ToString Then
      drwMerge("ORDFISCYR") = drwSqlServer("ORDFISCYR")
      drwMerge("ORDFISPER") = drwSqlServer("ORDFISPER")
      drwMerge("ORDNUMBER") = drwSqlServer("ORDNUMBER")
      Exit For
    End If
  Next drwSqlServer
Next drwMerge
'dtbMerged now contains the merged data'
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the sql column does not display data, only displays the title.